# Buttons dropping off screen

Tags: android, xml, button, view, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a button based menu using relative layout. I am trying to lay them out in a grid formation using the

```
android:below=""
android:above=""
android:toLeftOf=""
android:toRightOf=""
```

commands

I tried to add one more button below the three buttons I already had, but instead of the buttons resizing to fit the parent the fourth button instead drops below the screen edge. Is there a work around for this because I don't want buttons to appear missing on smaller screens. Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/level1layout" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

 <Button android:id="@+id/OneLevel1Button"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:text="1"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:background="@drawable/warpbutton"
 android:visibility="gone"/>

  <Button android:id="@+id/OneLevel2Button"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_below="@id/OneLevel1Button"
 android:text="2"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:background="@drawable/warpbutton"
 android:visibility="gone"/>

 <Button android:id="@+id/OneLevel3Button"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_below="@id/OneLevel2Button"
 android:text="3"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:background="@drawable/warpbutton"
 android:visibility="gone"/>

 <Button android:id="@+id/OneLevel4Button"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_below="@id/OneLevel3Button"
 android:text="4"
 android:textSize="25dp"
 android:background="@drawable/warpbutton"
 android:visibility="gone"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The visibilities are set to gone by default because they are hidden deeper in the menu system on start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a GridLayout?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

At OP's suggestion, a very helpful site creating a [custom ButtonAdapter](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)for a`GridView`.

Comment: can I set its visibility easily and possibly have more than one running in the same activity? Oh and can I replace the images used [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) with buttons?

Comment: I'm going to backpedal here and provide the original link I was going to provide - http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Can you post a screenshot or mock-up of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As much as a really don't want to say it I guess its like the angry birds level select menu. The one with the small numbered squares in a grid layout.

Comment: like these non-angry dogs?  http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/images/hello-gridview.png  It seemed from your OP that you want three columns of buttons.

I have made a button menu that has two LinearLayouts arranged side-by-side within a RelativeLayout.  Depending on how large you want the buttons, I would think you could do what I've done, but with three LinearLayouts next to each other.

Comment: Can I use buttons instead of images in a grid view?

Comment: Anyway I think I got it can you add [this site](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/) as a reference in your answer please, using a gridview was a fantastic suggestion.